# converting String to byte array and byteArray to string

Tags: nsstring, arrays

I have bytes data in local file, but how to convert that text into byte array and also getting original information from that data.

the file containing following data in txt file

[80,75,3,4,20,0,6,0,8,0,0,0,33,0,170,247,88,164,122,1,0,0,20,6,0,0,19,0,8,2,91,67,111,110,116,101,110,116,95,84,121,112,101,115,93,46,120,109,108,32,162,4,2,40,160,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,204,84,201,106,195,48,16,189,23,250,15,70,215,18,43,73,161,148,18,39,135,46,199,54,144,244,3,20,107,108,139,216,146,208,76,210,228,239,59,118,22,74,200,130,105,160,189,216,216,210,188,101,134,121,131,209,170,42,163,37,4,52,206,38,162,23,119,69,4,54,117,218,216,60,17,159,211,183,206,163,136,144,148,213,170,116,22,18,177,6,20,163,225,237,205,96,186,246,128,17,87,91,76,68,65,228,159,164,196,180,128,74,97,236,60,88,62,201,92,168,20,241,103,200,165,87,233,92,229,32,251,221,238,131,76,157,37,176,212,161,26,67,12,7,47,144,169,69,73,209,235,138]

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you are asking for

```
NSString *text = @"[80,75,3,4,20,0,6,0,8,0,0,0,33,0,170,247,88,164,122,1,0,0,20,6,0,0,19,0,8,2,91,67,111,110,116,101,110,116,95,84,121,112,101,115,93,46,120,109,108,32,162,4,2,40,160,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,204,84,201,106,195,48,16,189,23,250,15,70,215,18,43,73,161,148,18,39,135,46,199,54,144,244,3,20,107,108,139,216,146,208,76,210,228,239,59,118,22,74,200,130,105,160,189,216,216,210,188,101,134,121,131,209,170,42,163,37,4,52,206,38,162,23,119,69,4,54,117,218,216,60,17,159,211,183,206,163,136,144,148,213,170,116,22,18,177,6,20,163,225,237,205,96,186,246,128,17,87,91,76,68,65,228,159,164,196,180,128,74,97,236,60,88,62,201,92,168,20,241,103,200,165,87,233,92,229,32,251,221,238,131,76,157,37,176,212,161,26,67,12,7,47,144,169,69,73,209,235,138]";

// Delete the first and last character ('[' and ']')
text = [text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [text length] - 2)];

// Populate an array with the string representation of every number in the text file
NSArray *numbersAsStrings = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

// Declare an array of bytes
Byte byteData[[numbersAsStrings count]];

// Fill the byte array using the numbers from the text file
for (int i = 0; i < numbersAsStrings.count; i++) {
    NSString *currentNumber = [numbersAsStrings objectAtIndex:i];
    byteData[i] = [currentNumber intValue];
}

// Use the byte array to create an NSString represantation of the original text
NSString *convertedText = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteData length:sizeof(byteData) encoding:<#(NSStringEncoding)#>];

NSLog(@"%@", convertedText);
```

Just add the string encoding used to produce the file, you can find the full list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings).